# Submitting html form using PHP to display "Thank You" message in same div

Tags: php, html, forum

I am trying to create a simple forum using php to email the contents. Once the user clicks submit, I would like to have the div display a thank you message.

Currently going about this by trying to have the php write the html code using an if else statement. It seems the if statement is working, but the else statement is showing up as text.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "<form method="post" action="">
        <div class="field half first">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>  
        <div class="field half">    
        <label for="email">Email</label>        
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />       
        </div>
        <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>      
        </div>      
        <input class="button submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">    
        </form>";       

} else {
    $email_to = "field25farming@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Field 25 Contact Form";
    echo "Thanks! We'll get back to you soon."; 
} 
?>
```

You can see the problem in the bottom of the page here if you'd like: http://field25.com/

I'm also open to other ways of achieving this, thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery to submit the form and then updating the <div> that contains your form to then show the thank you message? I can give you some code in the form of an answer if you want to use this approach ...

Comment: I think you need to escape your quotations

Comment: @Chris I'm very unfamiliar with jQuery, but I'm willing to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that's rendering anything at all! There are a couple of problems. First, you have nested double quotes. Second, you're checking for the existence of the `submit` and if it exists, rendering the form. If it has to exist first, it'll never be rendered.

You can avoid the first problem entirely by simply dipping out of PHP. The second problem can be fixed by checking if `submit` does **not** exist via the `!` operator (or flipping the if/else output).

```
<?php
// if submit is not set, we want to render the form.
if( !isset($_POST['submit']) ) { ?>

<!-- leave PHPlandia -->

<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="field half first">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="field half">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input class="button submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<?php
} else {
    $email_to = "field25farming@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Field 25 Contact Form";

    // ... rest of your email sending code here ...

    echo "Thanks! We'll get back to you soon.";
}

?>
```

Comment: I just tried to run that, but nothing happens when I press the submit button, the form was still there. So I'm definitely not understanding something, if you could help me out.

This can all be done from one .html file correct? I'm not missing some outside link am I?

Comment: @Morgan Yes but it needs to be a `.php` file, not an `.html` file. That would explain why the version you posted didn't choke out immediately. Trying changing the file to `index.php` instead of (assuming here) `index.html`.

Comment: I changed the index to .php and pushed the file to the server. The code at the base of the form has gone away, however nothing happens when I click submit. Thanks for your help so far though.

Comment: @Morgan Rip out the JS block from lines 43-52 in `main.js`. Starts with `$('form').on('click','.submit`...` It's not doing anything for you and is preventing your form from submitting. If that's not possible for some reason, remove the class `submit` from the button in the HTML.